# Update multiple pods based on labels

Tags: kubernetes, label, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

I have the following situation:

I have multiple deployments running the same image and are configured identically except for the environmental variables.

Now my question is, is there an easy way to update for example the image of all these deployments instead of doing it one by one?

I haven't found a solution, but I think this should be possible with the use of labels?

Or is there a better way to deploy the same deployments with only different environmental variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, this is what labels are for. They are good for grouping similar objects.
Here is the minimal reproducible example.
Create 2 deployments with the same label `app=nginx`:

```
$ kubectl run --image=nginx --overrides='{ "metadata": {"labels": {"app": "nginx"}}, "spec":{"template":{"spec": {"containers":[{"name":"nginx-container", "image": "nginx"}]}}}}' nginx-1
deployment.apps/nginx-1 created
$ kubectl run --image=nginx --overrides='{ "metadata": {"labels": {"app": "nginx"}}, "spec":{"template":{"spec": {"containers":[{"name":"nginx-container", "image": "nginx"}]}}}}' nginx-2
deployment.apps/nginx-2 created
```

Here are our deployments:

```
$ kubectl get deploy -o wide --show-labels 
NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS        IMAGES   SELECTOR      LABELS
nginx-1   1/1     1            1           20s   nginx-container   nginx    run=nginx-1   app=nginx,run=nginx-1
nginx-2   1/1     1            1           16s   nginx-container   nginx    run=nginx-2   app=nginx,run=nginx-2
```

Then we can use `set` command and filter desired deployments using label `app=nginx`:

```
$ kubectl set image deployment -l app=nginx nginx-container=nginx:alpine
deployment.extensions/nginx-1 image updated
deployment.extensions/nginx-2 image updated
```

And see the results:

```
$ kubectl get deploy -o wide --show-labels
NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE     CONTAINERS        IMAGES         SELECTOR      LABELS
nginx-1   1/1     1            1           6m49s   nginx-container   nginx:alpine   run=nginx-1   app=nginx,run=nginx-1
nginx-2   1/1     1            1           6m45s   nginx-container   nginx:alpine   run=nginx-2   app=nginx,run=nginx-2
```